# Is it possible to install 2 versions of Python on Windows?

Tags: windows, python

Is it possible to install 2 versions of Python on Windows 7 and if so do I just need to run the separate installers? (and all will work well if I do, without any configuration?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes. I suggest installing the version you will use the most last**, because the installer <strike>adds Python to your system path</strike> adds registry entries for *.py files. These registry entries set the default "Open" action and add an "Edit with IDLE" context menu.

**To use a specific version of Python, simply use the full path to the executable.** And/or [set the appropriate environment variables](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) (`%PATH%` and `%PYTHONPATH%`) properly. This can be done at a Windows-wide level, then later over-ridden by a specific CMD console.

---

**Update:**

I just installed three versions of Python (2.5, 2.7,  then 2.6) on Windows 7. I wanted to be able to specify which version of Python to use for "Open with IDLE", so I added some registry keys under: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\` **in order to get two context menu items (`Edit with IDLE 2.6` and `Edit with IDLE 2.7`):**

1. I cloned the existing `Edit with IDLE` key to create a new `Edit with IDLE 2.7` key.
2. Then I modified the string under the `command` key to use Python 2.7:
   `"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -n -e "%1"`
3. Finally, I renamed the existing `Edit with IDLE` to `Edit with IDLE 2.6`
4. I could have added another context menu item for Python 2.5, but I only plan to use 2.5 infrequently for Google Apps Engine.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the formal way to do this is as follows:

Just install two (or more, using their installers) versions of Python on Windows 7 (for me work with 3.3 and 2.7).

Follow the instuctions below, changing the parameters for your needs.

Create the following environment variable (to default on double click):

```
Name:  PY_PYTHON
Value: 3
```

To launch a script in a particular interpreter, add the following shebang (beginning of script):

```
#! python2
```

To execute a script using a specific interpreter, use the following prompt command:

```
> py -2 MyScript.py
```

To launch a specific interpreter:

```
> py -2
```

To launch the default interpreter (defined by the PY_PYTHON variable):

```
> py
```

**Resources**

Documentation: [Using Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html)

[PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) - Python launcher for Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no problem. I have it on my Windows 7 64 bit machine - I think i have Python 2.5 and 2.7 - each one was installed with other software - I think that one with Scidavis and second with Quantum GIS. Both programs are working OK. ;-)